# How to test subscriptions "in_app_purchase"?

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-billing, billing

I use official plugin for [in app purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) in my app. I used subscriptions in my app. Now I get subscriptions list, but when I click on buy I get this error:

```
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play
```

These are the steps I followed:

-added "com.android.vending.BILLING" permission
-signed my apk
-published my apk to alfa and beta channel
-IAB products are published  and active
-Test account(s) is added in developer console

I try to download(for alfa or beta channels) or run a signed package (same version) but I only get this error.

Comment: check if the version code of the project you're running is the same published on beta/alpha distribution

Comment: yes, code is equal

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This is my bug - I added test account to another developer account. when i added this to the correct account it worked.